# Form error in my PHP code

Tags: php, forms

Well, have been recently learning PHP for a project. So, to practice, I'm trying forms:
The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Raportoni</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p></br></p>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
Emri : <input type="text" name="emri">
</br></br>
Mbiemri : <input type="text" name="mbiemri">
</br></br>
Adresa : <input type="text" name="adresa">
</br></br>
Numri i telefonit : <input type="text" name="numri">
</br></br>
Email : <input type="text" name ="email">
</br></br>
Nje pershkrim i shkurter i asaj qe ju ka ndodhur : </br> <textarea name="pershkrim"></textarea>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Dergo">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $emri=$_POST["emri"];
    $mbiemri=$_POST["mbiemri"];
    $adresa=$_POST["adresa"];
    $numri=$_POST["numri"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pershkrim=$_POST["pershkrim"];
    echo $emri;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to use it, it gives me this:

Notice: Undefined index: emri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: mbiemri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: adresa in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: numri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: email in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: pershkrim in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 12
Help please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `<form action="form.php" method="get">` and you're fetching POST

Comment: Check your $_POST first then store the values of form  `if(!empty($_POST)){ $emri=$_POST["emri"]; ..... }`

Comment: @dianuj that's good practice, but won't solve the problem

Comment: @DamienPirsy yup the problem was with request method

Comment: Yeah, and a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

Change your form method from:

```
 <form action="form.php" method="get">
```

to:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
```

Comment: also wrap the assignments in `isset()`. You'll get the undefined index values again if you visit form.php without posting to it.

Comment: Not working. Same problem.

Comment: @EnesKristo same error?

Comment: Yeah. It just keeps happening

Comment: Is your form.php in the same route than your html file?

Comment: Indeed. Same folder, localhost and all the other needed stuff

Comment: Well, they have no value set in the form...

Comment: @EnesKristo do you write anything in the inputs before submitting the form?

Comment: drop the html code from the php file and try again... `<!DOCTYPE html> ... <body>` and `</body> </html>`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: emri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: mbiemri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: adresa in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: numri in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: email in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: pershkrim in G:\USB WEB Server\root\butoni\form.php on line 7

And this comes out

Comment: @EnesKristo what does this code `print_r($_POST);` displays?

Answer (score 2):

You have your form on

```
method="get">
```

So in PHP you should use $_GET insted of $_POST.

Or better yet, set method to

```
method="post">
```

Because you are posting to form.php

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to POST and your indexes will become valid ie defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try it 
form.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['emri'])){$emri=$_POST['emri'];}
if(isset($_POST['mbiemri'])){$mbiemri=$_POST['mbiemri'];}
if(isset($_POST['adresa'])){$adresa=$_POST['adresa'];}
if(isset($_POST['numri'])){$numri=$_POST['numri'];}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email=$_POST['email'];}
if(isset($_POST['pershkrim'])){$pershkrim=$_POST['pershkrim'];}
echo $emri; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php code should be inside `if(!empty($_POST)){}`
Example:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $emri=$_POST["emri"];
    $mbiemri=$_POST["mbiemri"];
    $adresa=$_POST["adresa"];
    $numri=$_POST["numri"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pershkrim=$_POST["pershkrim"];
    echo $emri;
}
?>
```